# Is it possible to create a python sqlite3 function to create generic tables

Tags: python

I’m trying to create a python program which logs stock prices over certain periods of time, then creates a table for the individual stock where I can record the buy price and sell price of the stock at given times.

However, I don’t want to have to code individual tables for each stock, I’d rather code a function which lets me put variables as the table/column name, and have a series of variables in a list which i can then run the function and create 5 tables from a list for example.

So far I’ve gotten:

```
def create_tables(s,bp,sp,Time):
    sql_command = """
    CREATE TABLE """s"""( 
    Stock_number INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
    """bp""" INTEGER, 
    """sp""" INTEGER, 
    """Time""" VARCHAR(30));"""
    cursor.execute(sql_command)
```

I’m trying to execute this in a loop

```
for i in stock:
   create_tables(stock[x],buy[x],sell[x],time)
   x = x + 1
```

But it just doesn’t work.

Comment: Why don't you use *one* table and make the stock a column in this table?

Comment: To concatenate strings (add them together), use the `+` operator: `"hello" + x + "world"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Build your SQL  using [`format`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.format):

```
sql_command = """
CREATE TABLE {} ( 
  Stock_number INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, 
  {} INTEGER, 
  {} INTEGER, 
  {} VARCHAR(30));""".format(s,bp,sp,Time)
```